# POST contents of a form to rest api

Tags: javascript, html, http, rest

I have made a html user login form:

```
<html >
<head>

<title>User Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signin.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-signin">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
<input class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="" required="" placeholder="Email address">
<input class="form-control" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password">
<label class="checkbox">

</label>
<a href= "" <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button></a>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I now need to send the contents of the form, ie the username and password, to a rest api for authentication using the http POST command. I have no idea where to start with this and am having trouble finding a tutorial which assumes absolutely no knowledge of rest APIs and http commands. I'm extremely new to web development, can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial, or show me an example of what the javascript (I presume) might look like?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First fix your HTML.  Then with the following no javascript is necessary:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="URL_OF_REST">
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="email" placeholder="Email address">
  <input class="form-control" type="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <label class="checkbox"></label>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Carter- does this automatically take in the parameters of username and password?

Comment: Almost forgot to add name attributes to the form fields.  Usually you want form names for this method of form submission.  Make sure to put in the correct URL in the action param of `form` and you will be golden.  Good luck.

Comment: I tried this and found that HTML forms use POST whereas the RESTful API needs a "PUT".  I found a workaround to use javascript to execute the PUT.

Comment: REST API's can accept a PUT or a POST depending on their implementation.  PUT is typically for updating an existing record and POST is used for creating a new record.  I don't think html forms support a PUT method being specified, but you can hook into the `onsubmit` event of a form, take the data from the form and submit it via javascript with a PUT.